# Type: Mismatch VBA Error - Code not working

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I keep getting a type mismatch error on the below code (indicated next to line), whats interesting is that the macro was running but when I emailed it to myself on another computer it broke. Any idea how to fix this?

To give background, the macro is is for a user form that logs issues into different tabs (depending on what the issue is). When the issue is marked as complete, the issue is moved into the "5. Complete and Verified" tab, assigning the row a number, and adding in a column stating how many days it took to complete the issue. When the issue is moved out of the source tab, it is copied, deleted, then added into the 5. Complete and Verified tab.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Complete()

Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Set sourceWS = ActiveSheet
Dim destWS As Worksheet
Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified")

Dim RowCountS, RowCountD As Long

Dim intLastRowSrc As Long
RowCountS = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
intLastRowSrc = sourceWS.Cells(RowCountS, 1).End(xlUp) + 1'Type Mistmatch

Dim intLastRowSDes As Long
RowCountD = Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Rows.Count
intLastRowSDes = destWS.Cells(RowCountD, 2).End(xlUp) + 1 'Type Mismatch

Dim r As Long

Dim iRow2 As Long
iRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("B:B")) + 1

Dim iRow3 As Long
iRow3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceWS.Range("A:A")) + 1


Dim LastRow4 As Long
Dim LastRow5 As Long


For r = intLastRowSrc To 2 Step -1
        If sourceWS.Cells(r, "R") = "Complete & Verified" Then
            intLastRowSDes = destWS.Cells(RowCountD, 2).End(xlUp) + 2
            destWS.Range("C" & intLastRowSDes & ":S" & intLastRowSDes).Value = sourceWS.Range("B" & r & ":R" & r).Value
            sourceWS.Rows(r).Delete
            destWS.Cells(intLastRowSDes, 1) = sourceWS.Name ' Adding tab name as the Payer
            destWS.Cells(iRow2, 2) = iRow2 - 1 ' Numbering the rows in order instead of copying number from payer tab
            
            'Adding in Column for Days to Complete
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Cells(2, 20) = "=IF(RC[-3]="""",0,RC[-3]-RC[-9])"
            LastRow5 = Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'last row filled number row number not cell value 'need to copy before pasting
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("T2").Copy
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("T2" & ":" & "T" & LastRow5).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas) 'paste formulas
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("A1") = "Payor"
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("A1") = "Payor"
            Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified").Activate
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
            ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

            'Renumbering the No. Column on the Payer Tab
            sourceWS.Activate
            
            If IsEmpty(sourceWS.Range("A2")) = False Then
                LastRow4 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'last row filled number row number not cell value 'need to copy before pasting
                If (LastRow4 = 2) Then
                sourceWS.Range("A2") = 1
                Else
                sourceWS.Range("A2") = "=ROW()-1"
                sourceWS.Range("A2").Copy
                sourceWS.Range("A2" & ":" & "A" & LastRow4).FillDown 'paste formula
                End If
                sourceWS.Calculate
                sourceWS.Range("A2" & ":" & "A" & LastRow4).Copy
                sourceWS.Range("A2" & ":" & "A" & LastRow4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Range("A2").Select
            
    End If
    End If

Next



Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sourceWS.Cells(RowCountS, 1).End(xlUp) returns a Range Reference and you can't add a number to a Range. Try: sourceWS.Cells(RowCountS, 1).End(xlUp).Row() + 1 and you should have a valid row number.

Comment: No parentheses on the end though, just `.Row`.